# Problems with Eureka server

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have a local eureka server and one client

Eureka:

```
server:
 port: 1111

eureka:
 instance:
   prefer-ip-address: true
 client:
   registerWithEureka: false
   fetchRegistry: false
   serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:1111/eureka/
 server:
   waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

Client:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    serviceUrl:
    defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:1111/eureka/
```

I have 2 problems:

1) Eureka server throws in log:

> NullPointerException: 
>       at com.netflix.eureka.resources.StatusResource.isReplicaAvailable

2) The client connecting with Eureka, but after some time I see in his log next:

> RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error
>   javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: null at com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider.readFrom(DiscoveryJerseyProvider.java:110)
>
> RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failure
>   DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MW/192.168.0.100:client:8080 - was unable to send heartbeat!
>
> com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server

In log Eureka I see:

> InstanceRegistry      : DS: Registry: lease doesn't exist, registering resource: CLIENT - 192.168.0.100:client:8080
>   InstanceResource    : Not Found (Renew): CLIENT - 192.168.0.100:client:8080

In Eureka web console the client has a UP status, but also there is a big inscription:

> RENEWALS ARE LESSER THAN THE THRESHOLD. THE SELF PRESERVATION MODE IS
>   TURNED OFF.THIS MAY NOT PROTECT INSTANCE EXPIRY IN CASE OF
>   NETWORK/OTHER PROBLEM

Although connection is working and I can get link to my client throught Eureka.

Could you explain what it means and how I can get rid from that?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: thanks for your hint, i've figured out that my server and client were using different version

Answer (score 6):

```
serviceUrl:
defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:1111/eureka/
```

in client setting YML, you should add space before "defaultZone" like this:

```
serviceUrl:
  defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:1111/eureka/
```

else defaultZone is same level with serviceUrl.
thanks